# How can I convert a TRTTIInstanceType obj reference to its actual object reference?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use extented RTTI features This is where i stuck.

```
t := (c.FindType('Classes.TStringList') as TRttiInstanceType);
SL := t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]);
t.GetMethod('Add').Invoke(SL,['Hello Do you like my hat?']);
Lines := t.GetProperty('Text').GetValue(SL.AsObject);
```

Untill now it works fine
Now i want to alter the value

```
Lines := 'Test';

t.GetProperty('Text').SetValue(**?**,Lines);
```

What should i give here the TRTTIinstancetype reference or the actual object reference.
If Actual Object reference how will i give that.

```
TestStringList := t(**how will i get the actual object from this TRTTIinstancetype**).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Instance` parameter of `SetValue` is exactly the same as the `Instance` parameter of `GetValue`. So you simply need to pass exactly what already did when you called `GetValue`. Namely `SL.AsObject`:

```
t.GetProperty('Text').SetValue(SL.AsObject, Lines);
```

---

Regarding the very final part of your question, if you ever need to convert `SL` into an object with a specific class, `TStringList` in this case then you can use a runtime cast:

```
MyStringList := SL.AsObject as TStringList;
```

However, doing that rather implies that you don't need to be using RTTI in the first place. Using the method in the first part of my answer is the RTTI way to do what you ask.

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan & Linas

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you intend to use Rtti for all these tasks I will answer how it should be done correctly but in this case some usage of Rtti could be avoided. E.g.:

Since you are creating your stringlist with this line:

```
SL := t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]);
```

You can later use it as TStringlist and there is no need to use Rtti:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
...
begin
...
    SL := (t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]).ASObject) as TStringList;
```

So you can call:

```
SL.Text := Lines;
```

Instead of:

```
t.GetProperty('Text').SetValue(SL.AsObject,Lines);
```

But if you want to use Rtti for all of these tasks, you should'nt be doing something like this:

```
SL := t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[]);
```

What if method Create isn't a constructor? It is OK for TStringList but it could fail for some other types. Better to have separate function for creating objects using Rtti or use plain TClass for this task:

If you want to call constructor without parameters:

```
SL := t.MetaclassType.Create;
```

Another option:

```
function CreateType(AType: TRttiType): TObject;
var
  AMethCreate: TRttiMethod;
  instanceType: TRttiInstanceType;
begin
  if AType.IsInstance then
  begin
    for AMethCreate in AType.GetMethods do
    begin
      if (AMethCreate.IsConstructor) and (Length(AMethCreate.GetParameters) = 0) then
      begin
        instanceType := AType.AsInstance;
        Result := AMethCreate.Invoke(instanceType.MetaclassType, []).AsObject;

        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

...

```
var
  SL: TObject;

SL := CreateType(c.FindType('Classes.TStringList'));
```

...

```
t.GetProperty('Text').SetValue(SL,Lines);
```

Comment: It sounds logical, but it is incorrect. This code does not compile. SL is a `TValue`. But `SetValue` instance parameter is a `Pointer`. See my answer for the correct way to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is correct if SL is declared as TStringList.

Comment: Quite clearly SL is TValue. I'm very sorry, but this answer is just incorrect. I don't see any reason for it to remain. It is misleading.

Comment: Now you don't answer the question that was asked. Typically when one is using Rtti, one does not know what type the object is. So compile time determination of type is not possible. I honestly don't know what you are trying to do here. I have answered the question correctly. The answer is simple. Now is the time to show some grace. For a start you have an upvote gained when your answer is completely different. Since you know the upvote was gained on an incorrect, different answer, you should delete the answer that has the bogus upvote, and start again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm only trying to help. If the usage of Rtti could be avoided then I think it should be done so. I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: I know. I'm trying to help you with some Stack Overflow etiquette. You should not edit your answer in my view. You should delete it so that you don't carry on the pretence that the upvote means you answer is good. Then if you want to start again with an accurate answer you may do so. It would look a lot like my answer though....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In my edited answer I didn't remove older parts of it, I improved it with further examples.

Comment: Your answer still has errors. Code that doesn't compile and so on. There's not much point in me continuing to point out your errors for you. I don't see why I should do that. You obviously aren't listening to me which is your choice clearly. I'm disappointed that you got the answer so badly wrong and then had me correct you without even a hint of acknowledgement.

Comment: "In my edited answer I didn't remove older parts of it, I improved it with further examples." That's not true. Take a look at the first version of your answer. The one that doesn't compile. And that's the crux of the question. That's the bit that needs to be answered. You got it wrong. I corrected you. And you failed to acknowledge that. You took my knowledge and tried to pretend that you were right all along. Very shabby behaviour.

Comment: Oh dear oh dear...I took your knowledge??? I'm very sorry if this is how things looks to you but you are dead wrong. I just missed SL type and corrected it later. In this scenario I can also say that you copied my knowledge by editing your answer (you added a typecast to TStringList which was present in my answer earlier).

Comment: I cannot see `SL.AsObject as TStringList` in any of your answers. You can see from the comments to the answer what happened. It's very clear. You made a mistake (we all do), but it was how you responded to me pointing out that mistake that disappoints me. Anyway, I'm not going to point out the mistakes in the answer as it stands and let you do so.